# Is this a legitimate use of the Abstract Factory pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns

Here's what I'm trying to implement in my program:

- The program should open a zip file, which contains many data files
- The format of the data files can differ between zip files (e.g. csv, tab delimited, or could even be some kind of binary file which needs decoding)
- However, within a zip file all data files will be of the same type

I have been reading "Design Patterns" by Gamma et al., and have been looking at the Abstract Factory pattern to try to solve this.

Ideally, I want to have one class for the Zip file, which can read any type of data file within it. I guess I would have two classes - FileTypeA and FileTypeB, which could process different formats of data (although there could be more in the future). I would like a way of telling my ZipFile class which type of file to use when reading the data.

So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
<?php

/**
 * An abstract factory used for creating data files of any type
 */
abstract class DataFileFactory{
    abstract function createFile($id);
}

/**
 * A factory for creating and setting up a data file of type 'A'
 */
class FileAFactory extends DataFileFactory{
    public function createFile($id){
        $file = new FileA();
        $file->setSampleId($id);
        return $file;
    }
}

/**
 * A factory for creating and setting up a data file of type 'B'
 */
class FileBFactory extends DataFileFactory{
    public function createFile($id){
        $file = new FileB();
        $file->setSampleId($id);
        return $file;
    }
}

/**
 * An abstract class which defines some functionality of a data file
 */
abstract class DataFile{
    abstract function readData();
    abstract function setSampleId();
}

/**
 * Concrete class that processes a data file of type 'A'
 */
class FileA extends DataFile{
    public function readData(){
        echo "Reading data from a file A<br/>";
    }

    public function setSampleId(){
        echo "Setting sample id of a file A<br/>";
    }
}

/**
 * Concrete class that processes a data file of type 'B'
 */
class FileB extends DataFile{
    public function readData(){
        echo "Reading data from a file B<br/>";
    }

    public function setSampleId(){
        echo "Setting sample id of a file B<br/>";
    }
}

/**
 * Concrete class that reads a zip file and reads each file within the zip
 */
class ZipFile{
    private $files = array("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt");//this would be an array read from the zip file
    private $sampleId = 1;//this would be derived from some other function

    /**
     * Read all the files in a zip archive.
     * $factory can be an instance of any class that extends DataFileFactory, and is used for creating each file
     */
    public function readFiles(DataFileFactory $factory){
        foreach($this->files as $fileName){//loop through each file in the zip
            $file = $factory->createFile($this->sampleId);//use the factory to create the desired file
            $file->readData();//now read the data from the file!
            echo "object created of type: ".get_class($file)."<hr/>";
        }
    }
}

/***********************************************************************************************
 * IMPLEMENTATION
 ***********************************************************************************************/
$zip = new ZipFile();//create a new zip file
$factory = new FileAFactory();//instantiate a new factory, depending on which type of file you want to create
$zip->readFiles($factory);//read the files, passing the correct factory object to it
```

Can anyone tell me:
(A) Whether this is a good way of achieving what I'm looking for, or is there some simpler way of doing it?
(B) Is this actually the Abstract Factory pattern, or have I completely misunderstood?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just off on a tangent here, but have you considered the use of traits to handle some of your "copy & paste" methods? In your example: readData() and setSampleId().

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - however, I'm on PHP v5.3.5, and traits only from v5.4.0! Any other suggestions/answers would be welcome!

Comment: Yes, I do have another suggestion... change to 5.4 ^_^. But if I have something useful to add, I will :)

Comment: Okay, I don't know how good I am with "patterns" and such (I far prefer chaos), but what I might do differently (UNTESTED!) is pass the factory class as a parameter to the ZipFile __construct() and create the new factory in the __construct. For example, the implementation would be
`$zip = new ZipFile('FileA');// Create $this->factory = new FileAFactory() object in __construct // $zip->readFiles();` and readFiles would change to `$file = $this->factory->createFile($this->sampleId);`... I think ;)

Comment: Even better: get the __construct() to check the extension of the first file and auto-magically determine the required factory. Makes changing your code much easier and less opportunity for "human error" :P

Comment: Thanks again for your advice - I think your first suggestion is a good idea, although I would still pass in a factory object rather than a string so that I could use type-hinting. From what I've read, it seems that dependency injection in the constructor is better practice than injection into methods.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know about that one. I think it depends on the circumstances and the person writing the opinion. What I do know is that if you decide to refactor the implementation aspect, that is a whole lot of "find and replace" ;). If you put it in the constructor, it's all in one place, nice and neat! You could always do a kind of type-hinting dependency checking autoloader if/then in the constructor as well. Here's a fun article: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dependency-injection-is-evil.html ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a good implementation but it can be finetuned a bit if you use interfaces.

An abtract class with all virtual methods it's just a interface so don't use abstract classes, use [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

```
interface IDataFileFactory{
    public function createFile($id);
}

class FileAFactory implements IDataFileFactory
class FileBFactory implements IDataFileFactory
```

If you find repeating code in `FileAFactory` and in `FileBFactory` methods then it is time to refactor your classes and create inheritance.

```
interface IDataFileFactory{
    public function createFile($id);
}

abstract class BaseFileFactory implements IDataFileFactory {

//some methods implementation with common features to avoid repeating code
//some abstract methods to be implemented for A and B FileFactories
//absolute abstract base class has no sense because in php you can use interfaces.
//...
}

class FileAFactory extends BaseFileFactory
class FileBFactory extends BaseFileFactory
```

Then use throug interface:

```
  public function readFiles(IDataFileFactory $factory){
           //create a file using factory
           return IDataFile; //return Interface implemented by all DataFile types.
        }
```

You can do the same thing with `DataFile` base class and so on.

I also recomend to not pass factories in parameters because a factory is out of context. Try to do not mix architecture implementation with data and info process workflow. You can create a container, in a scope accesible for your other classes, to resolve the factory.

The container can, for example, read configuration files to create concrete factory in application bootstrap; read from some value, choosed by the user in previous steps of the user case, stored in a class instance or accepting a parameter in runtime to resolve the factory. It's about implement some kind of simple dependency inyection.

Anyway, this is only my point of view and can be a hurge amount disagreements.

I hope it help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I agree with you regarding using Interfaces instead - I don't think there is a reason to use an Abstract Class in this case. With regards to Dependency Injection, would it be better to do something like this? http://pastebin.com/3R7JH9nK

Comment: Although, in the book I'm reading the example code shows passing a factory as a parameter - I'm just wondering if putting that into a DI container would cause unnecessarily clutter...

Comment: What I mean is a static class (no instance) resolving the factory (reading from config file, setting an static attribute in previous process step, in app init or passing parameter) in a scope accesible for your services. Anyway, this is personal preferences from my experience. I like to keep process data workflow clean from architecture implementation. For me it's better pass $id (process data in the workflow) in parameter than factory or DI containers instances (architecture implementation).

Comment: Disclaimer: This is for simple applications. If the app is a bit complex I would move to a complete Dependenci Inyection framework to resolve the complete dependency chain.